# V2 react-select css styling issues

Tags: react-select

when using react-select v2, I can't figure out how to set the font of the input field.. 
I have tried the following:

```
input: (base) => ({
  ...base,
  fontFamily: 'Arial',
  fontSize: 13,
  fontWeight: 500,
  color: 'green'
})
```

the `color` is working accordingly but none of the other font styles are applied.

Also is there a way of setting the color of the `dropdownIndicator` on hover of the `control`?

Like:

```
control: (base, { isFocused }) => ({
  ...base,

  ':hover': {
  ### Set the dropdownIndicator Color
  },
}),
```

I know v2 is still in beta but I would really appreciate some help :)

Comment: Please share a codepen with your code. In your case, you can use 'components' props from react-select to manipulate options in menu and displayed value or write your custom css.

Comment: Have you tried adding `!important` to the end of your `fontFamily`?